# Add element to Map of String, Arraylist

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Working with the Google Maps API for Android (v2), I am trying to store some country Polygon approximations into a data structure, particularly, a map with String as keys (name of the country) and an ArrayList of PolygonOptions.

This var is private and declared by:

```
private Map<String, ArrayList<PolygonOptions>> worldMap;
```

But my code crashes when I try to fill it with a PolygonOption, in the following function:

```
private void addSomeCountry() {
        ArrayList <PolygonOptions> MyPoli = new ArrayList<PolygonOptions>();
        PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(42.569962, 1.78172 ))
                .add(new LatLng(42.509438, 1.723611))  
                .add(new LatLng(42.601944, 1.445833))  
                .add(new LatLng(42.569962, 1.78172)) 
                .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                .strokeColor(Color.CYAN);
        MyPoli.add(rectOptions);
        worldMap.put("Andorra", MyPoli);
    }
```

Specifically, it crashes with the following error:

```
04-04 21:20:30.335  22562-22562/otorrillas.geography E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: otorrillas.geography, PID: 22562
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
             at otorrillas.geography.DataSaver.addSomeCountry(DataSaver.java:49)
             at otorrillas.geography.DataSaver.onCreate(DataSaver.java:32)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see you initializing `worldMap` anywhere.

```
private Map<String, ArrayList<PolygonOptions>> worldMap = new HashMap<>();
```

should do.